# Windows10 | Powershell redirecting into Microsoft store

Tags: windows, powershell

I have updated my windows recently. Now I have windows with november update. And when I try to call python from powershell it redirect me into Microsoft Store for python3.7 download.

My environment variables is ok.

[Env vars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN9l9.png)

P.S.: Python3 package on my computer is ok, because PyCharm uses it.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason, Windows inserts some little helper apps to redirect you to the store to find common things.

from the command line:

```
cd %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WindowsApps
del python.exe 
del python3.exe
```

OR

Update your PATH environment variable such that your Python folder containing the real Python.exe is listed before the WindowsApps folder.

OR

Just take WindowsApps folder out of your PATH

Details on editing your PATH environment here: https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/

Comment: Removing 2 files from WindowsApps directory works, thank you ^^